# lambda Expression: Best practice for AND condition inside Where(TSource) Function

Tags: c#, if-statement, where-clause

Is there any good practice to write AND in lambda expression instated of writing the following IF inside Where() function

```
lst.Where(obj=> {
  if (obj.Prop1 == true && obj.Prop2 == true)
    return true;
  return false;
          });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any reason not to write:

```
lst.Where(obj => obj.Prop1 && obj.Prop2)
```

? In general:

- I avoid direct comparisons with true and false, preferring `if (foo)` to `if (foo == true)`
- When you have a code structure of:

  ```
  if (condition)
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  then you can just replace it with:

  ```
  return condition;
  ```

  That's just as true in lambda expressions as in anything else - except that with lambda expressions like yours, it means you can move from a *statement lambda* (braces surrounding the body) to an *expression lambda* (without braces).

The second point extends beyond just true and false, too, using the conditional operator. I would usually convert this:

```
if (condition)
{
    return x;
}
else
{
    return y;
}
```

to

```
return condition ? x : y;
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your support

Comment: @Jon: in conditional Operator, why I cant use it like this: *isHRUser() ? fillAllEmployees() : pnlUsers.Visible = false;*

Comment: @Remon: It's kinda hard to tell without knowing what `fillAllEmployees()` returns. A conditional expression has to be an *expression* with a value, not just a statement. If `fillAllEmployees()` is a void method, that would prevent it from being used here. (I would also suggest that you start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: @Jon; i altered the method to let return a boolean, but still the same, and about the naming conventions you may note that these two methods declared as private so first letter is small, is that your observation ?

Comment: @Remon: Well while private methods can use whatever convention you like, all the production code I've ever seen uses PascalCase for *all* methods. What error are you getting at the moment? What are you assigning the result of the expression to? (Again, it's an expression and can't be used as a statement on its own... to be honest it feels like this is probably a case where the conditional operator *isn't* appropriate.)

Comment: @Jon: You are completely right Jon, I just wanted to apply this technique *conditional Operator* here, to make this right it must hold the result back in some boolean var *As you said*, it works, bit i see its not that logical here in my case, thanks for clearing up the idea, have a nice day.